# Beautifulsoup way to get string value of a tag only if it exists in a concise way?

Tags: beautifulsoup

When I want to get the text of `<Dressing>Italian</Dressing>`:

```
salad = BeautifulSoup(salad_response.content, 'xml')
dressing = salad.find('Dressing').string
```

Unforunately if no dressing node is found, then the following exception is raised:

```
*** AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'string'
```

So I have to do I check first:

```
dressing = salad.find('Dressing')
if salad.find('Dressing'):
    dressing = salad.find('Dressing')
```

Can I do this in a more concise way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `if.. else` in oneline.

```
dressing = salad.find('Dressing').string if salad.find('Dressing') else None
```

The syntax is,
`A if condition else B`
If condition pass, then do A else do B.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the variable in the if condition.

```
dressing = salad.find('Dressing')
if dressing:
    print(dressing.text)
```

---

To check your result here is the examples.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
data='''<Dressing>Italian</Dressing>'''
salad = BeautifulSoup(data, 'xml')
dressing = salad.find('Dressing')
if dressing:
    print(dressing.text)
```

This will returns `Italian`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
data='''<Dressing1>Italian</Dressing1>'''
salad = BeautifulSoup(data, 'xml')
dressing = salad.find('Dressing')
if dressing:
    print(dressing.text)
```

This will return nothing.